# Find "path" in 2D array where path cells sum equals to "sum"

Tags: java, recursion, backtracking

Given 2D array of positive integers. A "path" is a collection of adjacent cells. Two cells are adjacent only from right/left/top/bottom (no diagonal).

The task is to write a function that receives a 2D array `mat`, an integer `sum` and a 2D array `path` (with same size as `mat`-empty array all zeros).

The function should check if path exist where the sum of cells equal to `sum`, should return true if exist and false otherwise.

The array `path` will mark the path (if exist with `1`).

For example if `mat` is:

[image]

and `sum=4`

then `path` can be one of these three:

[image]

**My code:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    int[][] mat={{2,41,3,14},
                 {2,1,24,7},
                 {2,15,10,54},
                 {63,22,2,4}};

    int[][] path={{0,0,0,0},
                  {0,0,0,0},
                  {0,0,0,0},
                  {0,0,0,0}};
    findSum(mat,4,path);
    //print(mat);
    print(path);
}
public static boolean findSum (int mat[][], int sum, int path[][])
{
    return findSum(mat,sum,path,0,0);
}

public static boolean findSum (int mat[][], int sum, int path[][],int i,int j)
{
    if(sum==0)                      
        return true;

    if(i==mat[0].length||j==mat[1].length)
        return false;       
    boolean result=findSum(mat,sum-mat[i][j],path,i,j+1)||findSum(mat,sum-mat[i][j],path,i+1,j);

    if(result)
        path[i][j]=1;
    return result;

}
private static void print(int[][] arr)
{
    for(int i=0;i<arr[0].length;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<arr[0].length;j++)
        {
            System.out.print(arr[i][j]+" ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

> My code works fine only if the path starts at (0,0) but does't work for other pathes, for example it doesn't work(path array is all zero) for `sum=16` even that there is such path.

Note:

- The function must be recursive- no loops at all.
- Global variables are not allowed (printing the array is not part of the question- only for test therefore there is a loop)

Comment: is the job to find possible paths or to see if the given path and sum are valid for the given matrix?

Comment: The task is to write a recursive function that recievs a `mat` (2D array of positive integers), a `sum`, and `path` (2D array of zeros). the function should resturn `true` if there is a path that his sum equlas to the given `sum` variable.

Comment: why are we setting values in path then?

Comment: sum must be reset and you must perform the entire check again on each cell. Additionally, this approach of only move right and down will not work if the path is shaped like the letter J.

Comment: @mavriksc that will show the cells that was in the path

Comment: you are not saying things clearly then. the function should either generate a path(or list of all possible paths) based on sum, or given a sum and path and source see if the path is valid.

Comment: @mavriksc My assumption (and that's all it can be with this limited information) is that the path is just there to pass state into the recursive function calls, to prevent retracing the same cells multiple times.  That would make it just an internal implementation detail that the teacher made sure to spell out to the students to keep them focused on learning recursion.

Comment: You only find paths that start at the upper left cell because it's the only place where you ever start your search, which happens precisely in `findSum(mat,sum,path,0,0);`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice question... Here is the answer. It was a fun code challenge ;)

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    int[][] mat={{2,41,3,14},
                 {2,1,24,7},
                 {2,15,10,54},
                 {63,22,2,4}};

    int[][] path={{0,0,0,0},
                  {0,0,0,0},
                  {0,0,0,0},
                  {0,0,0,0}};

    if ( findSum(mat,22,path) ) print(path);
    else System.out.println("No path found");
}
public static boolean findSum (int mat[][], int sum, int path[][])
{
    return startPath(mat, sum, path, -1, 0);
}

// Recursively check every possible starting point
public static boolean startPath(int mat[][], int sum, int path[][], int y, int x)
{
    // Iterate y, goto next column if necessary
    if (++y == mat.length) {
        y = 0;
        ++x;
    }

    if (x == mat[0].length) // Bounds check
        return false;

    if (findSum(mat, sum, path, y, x)) // We've found a successful start point!
    {
        System.out.println("A successful path starts at " + x + ", " + y);
        return true;
    }

    return startPath(mat, sum, path, y, x); // We'll have to keep looking
}

public static boolean findSum (int mat[][], int sum, int path[][], int i, int j)
{
    if(i==mat[0].length || j==mat[1].length || i<0 || j<0) // Bounds check
        return false;

    if (path[i][j] == 1) // Backtracking check
        return false;

    sum -= mat[i][j]; // Decrement sum

    if (sum >= 0) { // More to go? look around
        path[i][j] = 1;

        if (sum == 0) return true; // We made it!

         // If any path finds the end, don't try other paths
        boolean result = findSum(mat, sum, path, i+1, j);
        if (result) return true;
        result = findSum(mat, sum, path, i, j+1);
        if (result) return true;
        result = findSum(mat, sum, path, i-1, j);
        if (result) return true;
        result = findSum(mat, sum, path, i, j-1);

         // There was no successful paths, this is a dead end
        if (!result) path[i][j] = 0;
        return result;
    } else { // We're negative, overshot it
        return false;
    }
}

private static void print(int[][] arr)
{
    for(int i=0;i<arr[0].length;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<arr[0].length;j++)
        {
            System.out.print(arr[i][j]+" ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

By the way when checking multidimensional array dimensions you are meaning to do `arr.length and arr[0].length` but instead you are doing `arr[0].length and arr[1].length` which would get the same dimension twice and cause an error if the array was not a square.

I've also allowed moving in any direction, by using the intended path to prevent re-checking the same node again. This could probably be a boolean array. Sorry if my x/y recursion is rough looking... I really prefer loops or .forEach or => or .map for that...

The -1, 0 can be cleaned up perhaps with optional parameters and not iterating on the first pass.

Let me know if there are any errors or edge cases you may find.